# Mersenne Twister on Little Endian

Tags: c, random, endianness, pseudocode, mersenne-twister

Does the [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Pseudocode) provided in Wikipedia's article on Mersenne Twister work with Little Endian ("atomic element size" 8 or [16 bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Atomic_element_size_16-bit_2)), or any other byte-orderings?

Does it work on 32-bit only systems? (i.e. The number cannot be stored in anything bigger than a `DWORD`.)

**EDIT:** Also, what do they mean by `32nd bit of(MT[i])`? `MT[i] & (1 << 31)` or `MT[i] & 0x01` or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm gives you a number.  How you store it is irrelevant.

You can have 32-bit numbers on 16-bit systems (ex. C `long` was 32-bits on 16-bit Windows).

32nd bit means the high bit (MT[i] & (1<<31)).